# ActionView::MissingTemplate: if visit a :text page without explicit .txt added to url in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

In Rails 4.0 how do I specify a route to a :text page in such a way that I can visit the page without the format explicitly added?

Upgrading a Rails 3.2 app to Rails 4, the route fails when I try to visit a text page (both in Capybara and when running the app on a development box)

```
# in routes.rb
get 'blank_page' => "home#blank_page", :format => :text

# when rake routes:
blank_page GET   /blank_page(.:format)   home#blank_page

# in test_request.rb (Capybara 2.5.0, Rails 4.0, Rspec 3.3.0)
visit "/blank_page.txt" # works
visit "/blank_page"     # FAILS: ActionView::MissingTemplate:
visit blank_page_path   # FAILS: ActionView::MissingTemplate:
```

Running the app locally I see the same thing, visiting the localhost page /blank_page fails but /blank_page.txt works

Am I declaring the route and default :text format incorrectly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it, but instead of deleting question I'm posting an answer in case it helps someone else.

Looks like in Rails 4 your must use :defaults on the route

```
get 'blank_page' => "home#blank_page", :defaults => { :format => :text }
```